# How can I set this thread instead of starting it from 0?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class that works as a clock, as follows:

```
public class Playtime extends Thread {

public int playtimei = 0;
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true)
    {
        playtimei++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

which, in a new game for my program is started like this:

```
Data.playtime = new Playtime();
Data.playtime.start();
```

which causes it to start from zero; however, the game needs to be able to read an int from a save file and start from that number instead.

How do I start it with a specific int?

Comment: So the question is, "How do I read data from a text file"? You should try to do it by using google and your own brainpower then come back and ask a specific question when you have a specific problem.

Comment: No, the question is how to start playtime with a specific int instead of 0. The fact that the int gets read from a text file is extra information. Sorry if you got confused.

Comment: "_No, the question is how to start playtime with a specific int instead of 0_" Well starting playtime with something other than 0 is too easy. Just change one line `public int playtimei = 0;` to `public int playtimei = whatever#;`. This could not have been the confusing part. All that was left was the process of reading the int from a file `able to read an int from a save file` so I assumed that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just simple read your config time and in your class add constructor to Playtime.

```
public class Playtime extends Thread {

    int playtimei = 0;

    public Playtime(int playtimei) {
        this.playtimei = playtimei;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
            playtimei++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
int time = loadFromFile();
Playtime playtime = new Playtime(time);
```